# What is the function of AVDD,AVSS and Vref of ADC in Microcontoller?

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I want to know the function of `AVDD,AVSS and Vref` in Analog to Digital converter in a Microcontroller. If AVDD and AVSS represents the range of input voltage ,what is the function of Vref?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume based on the names you are talking about Atmel AVRs.

"AVDD" and "AVSS" are basically power supply and ground for the analogue portions of the circuitry. These must be connected to "VDD" and "VSS", but they are brought out separately so that you can add a filter on to "AVDD" for noise reduction, and so that digital noise doesn't get coupled onto the analogue ground.

"AREF" is an analogue reference voltage which allows you to configure the upper range of the ADC. When specified by register bits, AREF is used instead of AVDD to provide the ADC reference. The ADC range will be between AGND and AREF allowing you to use the full dynamic range of the ADC even if the peak amplitude of your input signal is smaller than the supply voltage.

Comment: Vdd does not generally need to be tied to AVdd.  I've had cases where they even required different values

Answer (score 2):

AVDD and AVSS are the supply voltages.

Most ICs cannot operate with voltages exceeding the supply rail voltages so that is how AVDD and AVSS determine the input voltage range. Exceed this voltage range and the ESD protection diodes will start to conduct causing all kind of weird (if you are unfamiliar with this) behavior.

The **value** of the supply voltage is assumed to be inaccurate and is thus not always suited as a **reference voltage** for an ADC.

An ADC needs some kind of reference value because it outputs a number and that number is related to the value of the input. If the input voltage is 1.00 V but the ADC has no idea "how much" 1.00 V is then it cannot output the correct number. For that a reference voltage is needed. The supply could be used but sometimes the supply voltage varies. So then a different (more accurate and stable) reference voltage can be supplied via the Vref pin.

Answer (score 0):

In standalone ADC' Vref is used as a reference point to determine the relative (in voltage) size of an LSB. Usually the formula is something to the effect of:

LSB (V) = Vref/(2^(ADC bits)-1)

Answer (score 0):

VREF has the burden of supplying the fast surges of current, as the ADC plows through its binary-search approximation. 
An ADC operating at 1Million conversions per second, with Cref of 10pF and with VREF of +5volts, needs F * C * Vref average current; that is 1e6 * 1e-11 * 5, or 5e-5 amps or 50 microAmps. Thus the source resistance of VREF is an error, appearing in FullScale accuracy.

If VREF is provided by an OpAmp, that OpAmp needs to recover from the sudden surge (100pS turnon) and charging demands of the 10pF cap. To ease this burden, place a substantial capacitor right by the VREF pin, and ground the bottom of the cap to AGND pin. Pay attention to currents flowing in the GND traces, because 100mA and 10 squares of trace (100mils by 10mils = 10 squares) is modeled as 100mA * (10 * 0.0005 ohms) = 100mA * 5 milliOhms = 500 microVolts.
If your ADC is 16 bits, you likely have LSBs of 60 microvolts or smaller, and some error --- 500uV/60uV == 9 LSBs --- will appear in FullScale or in ZeroScale performance of the ADC.