# How can an oscilloscope tolerate 400 Vpk input?

Tags: oscilloscope, high-voltage

I recently checked the input specifications of various oscilloscopes (i.e., SDS 1202X-e, [here](https://siglentna.com/wp-content/uploads/dlm_uploads/2020/02/SDS1000X-E_DataSheet_DS0101E-E04C.pdf)) and found that these kinds of BNC connector-type scopes can typically endure up to 400 V<sub>pk</sub> of input swing.

However, most of their analog components in the signal chain cannot reach that high voltage. For instance, SDS 1202X-E uses AD8370 and HMCAD1511 for its ADC driver and ADC, respectively. According to their specifications, their AVDD can take only up to 2~5 V.

How can they detect up to 400 V<sub>pk</sub> without damaging chips on the datapath?

Edit: My original posting missed few information, so I am adding extra information here.
Assumption: 1x passive probe (i.e., Siglent's PP510 or Keysight's 10070)
Scope's vertical scale setting: 1 V/div
Question: Typical oscilloscope's manual (or front-panel) does not specify the probe's attenuation setting nor scope's vertical scale setting. In this case, how come the ICs on the signal path in oscilloscope can operate without being damaged, while most of these ICs take analog VDD of <= 5V ?

Comment: A voltage divider.

Comment: @winny can you elaborate your answer a bit more? what do you mean by voltage divider? I know that typical scopes have a variable vertical scale that can go up to 10V/div, but even with 1:10 division does not seem it can tolerate the 400Vpk input. 

In addition, the warning message on the BNC connectors usually does not specify which vertical scale the scope is supposed to be set to before it takes 400Vpk input.

Comment: Do a search for voltage divider. There are several types.

Comment: 400Vpk is higher than the Vrms. And with a 1M Ω inout resistor, most power is already gone. Exception is the 50 Ω input, usually then max 5V input.

Comment: @Emm386 The 1:10 division is the *probe*; there's further division inside the scope itself.

Comment: AVDD = [analog power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279841/what-is-the-function-of-avdd-avss-and-vref-of-adc-in-microcontoller)

Comment: Use a 200V op-amp and a 2:1 divider with RC matched impedances.

Comment: To all above: Typical scopes have 10x-1x options in their probe (i.e., PP510). Plus, the front panel of scopes usually do not specify the vertical scale settings nor probe attenuation setting. Therefore, this implies that the scope front-end circuit can work even with 400 Vpk input regardless of probe's attenuation settings and scope's vertical scale setting. Now my question is how the signal path in the scope can endure 400 Vpk in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

Each input network has PGAs (programmable gain amplifiers) which are used to adjust the attenuation and amplification amounts dynamically, depending on the probe (e.g. 1x, 10x, 100x, etc) and volts/div settings.

Being able to withstand 400Vpk for an input means that there are dividers and clampers/limiters (protection) for 400Vpk. Because the logic inside can measure up to a few volts, the divided input signal should not exceed that low level. So the analog system inside the scope (which is called "signal conditioning") is there to bring a few volts to the logic/ADC system for 400Vpk regardless of the settings.

Think of the input section as a multiple-resistor divider and a digital rotary switch that selects the division ratio by activating respective resistors (These resistors make a total of 1 MOhm - input impedance):

[image]

This section follows a PGA and filtering for the required bandwidth. If you select 200V/div maximum attenuation can be applied to make a 300Vpk waveform visible. But the same attenuation can't be applied to, say, 1Vpk so by adjusting volts/div a different attenuation/amplification factor will be used. When you press AUTO button the scope will measure everything and find the best ratio available to bring best visible waveform.

Comment: I understand that there is a voltage divider inside of the scope. I guess my question was not specific enough. Let's say the scope's vertical scale is set to 1V/div by accident. And let's assume someone accidentally tried to probe 400Vpk signal. Can scope still be operating without damaging the circuitry inside?

Comment: @Emm386 the input will be attenuated (scaled down) to meaningful levels regardless i.e. even with the lowest volts/div the attenuation ratio won't be unity. So no, the logic never sees 400V.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer with more details? this is actually the main point of my question, and I would appreciate it if you can explain how ADC input does not see 400V even with lowest volts/div settings + typical 1x probe.

Comment: @Emm386 This is a common misconception so I want to correct it here--a 1x probe is not typical. 1x probes are rarely used and can't reach anything close to the bandwidth of the much more common 10x probes; you'd only use a 1x probe in very special circumstances.

Comment: @Hearth I understand you mean, but still, even 1x can endure up to 300 Vpk-pk (150 Vpk). reference is PP510 probe from Siglent. Even in this scenario, my question is still not changing: with 150 Vpk input and vertical scale of 1V/div, how can an oscilloscope operate without being damaged?

Comment: @Emm386 because there's **always an attenuation** inside the scope (via dividers like I showed), regardless of the probe and volts/div. I mean, even if 400Vpk is applied directly to the input the logic inside will see a few volts regardless of the settings thanks to the dividers. The microcomputer will do the calculations and mapping afterwards e.g. for 400V input the logic/ADC won't see 400V but it'll see, say, 4.0V. And for 1x probe and 100V/div it'll show you as 400V. The microcomputer will do the adjustments and calculations.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I believe this is the case when you press 'auto' button. Otherwise, the microcontroller will not react until a user provides input. Then what if a user does not press 'auto' button? Or how about an old analog oscilloscope like Tektronix 475?

Comment: @Emm386 This answer talks about clampers. To further elaborate, the simplest clamper is a diode, you hook a diode (or series of diodes) between the signal and ground. When the input signal hits the turn-on voltage of the diodes, it conducts, limiting the max voltage and protecting downstream ICs.

Comment: @Emm386 doesn't matter. Even if you apply 400Vpk to the BNC jack of the scope, the always-there-and-always-on resistive divider (which totals 1 MOhm or whatever the input impedance is) scales down that voltage so the logic sees much lower *(Note that I'm not talking about the dividers inside the probe, I'm talking about the dividers inside the scope, right after the BNC jack)*. The AUTO button changes the division ratio and PGA's amplification factor to bring the best visible waveform. For 400Vpk, regardless of any settings, the logic will never see 400V. Same applies to DMMs as well. ...

Comment: ... the microcomputer makes all the necessary calculations and map the voltage that the logic/ADC sees to the real input voltage. For example, it's like "I see a voltage of 4V, the division ratio is 1/1000, and the PGA is set to 10x, so the input voltage should be 400V" and shows it on the display. Remember that the division ratio will never be 1:1. Do you really think that the designers are that stupid to allow 400V to reach to the logic :)

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks for answering my question but I am not talking about if digital logics see 400 Vpk. I am talking about analog components sitting before ADC and this is why I brought AD8370 as an example (PGA driving ADC). Second, this is quite hard to believe that microcontroller will take care of everything "automatically" since it has no capability of knowing if the incoming signal is 100 V or 300 V (this is already way beyond ADC's dynamic range). With your logic, the scope will keep varying its vertical scales regardless of what it is set to on the front-panel.

Comment: @Emm386 First, I'm talking about analog components as well. There are dividers which can withstand 400V, just after the BNC. And they are the part of signal conditioning block. So, after the dividers there are PGAs to get "meaningful" signal levels for different input amplitudes. Second, I didn't say "microcontroller", I said "microcomputer". Sampling an input signal with 2 million times per second, making all the calculations, and displaying the results with a refresh rate of at least 30 Hz cannot be done with an ordinary microcontroller. And finally, with the AUTO function, ...

Comment: ... the microcomputer sweeps the available attenuation and gain ratios to find the "best meaningful" level. So, indeed it knows the signal level. How could it be possible to find the best volt/div and time/div without knowing the incoming signal's amplitude and frequency content?

Comment: @RohatKılıç I do have multiple questions regarding your comment but let's think about the following scenario: ADC sees 400 Vpk input voltage, and let's assume that microcomputer can detect and automatically adjust the gain and whatnot. But it can easily take few microseconds for the microcomputer to process all these data and feedback to PGA/attenuator settings. Over this few microsecond periods, the analog IC components are already exposed to extremely high voltage input while its AVDD is ~5V. This few microseconds is long enough to damage these analog IC components

Comment: @Emm386 Either I can't explain or you insist on not understanding. No, **the ADC will never see 400Vpk**. Before reaching the ADCs the input signal will be scaled down already by at least 1/100 **via the dividers after the BNC**. So in any case ADCs will see ≤5V. The microcomputer knows its zero and max, and is able to adjust the attenuation from, say, 1/100 to, say, 1/1000. If the signal is too low to measure the PGAs followed by dividers can be programmed to amplify the **scaled down** signal to get meaningful things. Think about how a 100mV signal would look like at 100V/div. This is ...

Comment: ... when the microcomputer makes the calculations when you pressed AUTO. The microcomputer calculates what value corresponds to what input voltage because it knows the attenuation and PGA. For example, for 200V input, if the attenuator is set to 1/200 and the PGA is set to 1, the ADC sees 1V (The attenuation can't be 1). And the microcomputer will calculate that the input voltage is 200V. Because it knows the attenuation and PGA gain. Likewise, in AUTO mode, it adjusts the attenuation and PGA until the ADC catches, say, at least 100 mV. But **in any case** the ADCs will **never** see 400 Vpk.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Okay, I guess we started circulating the question. I will also think about this from my side a little bit more. I do know that there is a divider existing in the front-end circuit, and this is how the vertical scaling works. As mentioned above, the problem with your comment is the latency b/w microcomputer and attenuation settings. this loop will easily take a few microseconds, which is long enough to make any analog IC go breakdown. This is why I'm suspecting there must be some analog circuit techniques instead.

Comment: Possibly this 400Vpk is referring to the clamp's maximum tolerable voltage, but I wanted clarification if this is correct or not.

Comment: @Emm386 look. Forget about the vertical scaling, latency, etc. Regardless of the settings, even if the scope is off, even if you apply 400V directly to the BNC, the ADCs inside won't see 400V. Attenuation is related to vertical scaling, yes, but partly. There's always a passive, default attenuation that scales down the input. Again, in **any** case, the ADCs will never see 400Vpk. This number is probably the scope's maximum measurement limit i.e. without distortion. At BNC side, there must be clampers or similar stuff to limit the input to (or slightly above) 400V.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Okay, now I got it. thanks for your patience. I also did my homework and research and confirmed that there is usually an "mechanical" attenuator (especially for real-time scopes) regardless of vertical scaling settings. I am still not 100% sure how this is setup in conjunction with PGA for vertical scalings. However, at least my curiosity is quenched.

Answer (score 2):

A digital storage oscilloscope (DSO) uses an ADC to capture waveforms. The DSO input range can from very small (mV) to very large (400 V) so the input range must be scaled up or down to meet what the ADC needs.

Scaling down can be done by the simplest of circuits: a two-resistor potential divider (shown below) with a top and bottom resistor.

However, the DSO has switchable input ranges so the actual divider resistors in use are changed by the range selection circuitry.

For small ranges below the ADC input range, the DSO input voltage must be amplified   or the ADC reference voltage dropped to meet the range. However, the former produces better quality conversions.

Note that your DSO's Analog Devices HMCAD1511 IC is a 'Multi-Mode A/D Converter' and so contains extra circuitry, such as some input scaling, as well as the analogue-to-digital converter (ADC) itself.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From reading the manual, I extract some data and present you with my design specs.
How it was implemented is irrelevant.  If you had this task, you are free to choose what works.

**Physical probes** . . . . .  1X , 10X, 100X, 1000X
Logical probe attenuation. . 0.1X, 0.2X, 0.5X, 1X, 2X, 5X, 10X......1000X, 2000X, 5000X, 10000X
ADC = 0 to 5V max
**Scale Vertical**
1x [/div] _  Gain
500 μV __  Av=1000
5 mV  ____   Av=100
50 mV ___    Av=10
500 mV __  Av=1
5 V ______    Av=0.1
10 V _____    Av=0.05    (corrected)

Offset Range (Probe 1X)
500uV~118mV:±2V,
120mV~1.18V:±20V,
1.2V~10V:±200V

[Ref 1](https://forum.seeedstudio.com/uploads/default/original/2X/9/9a874560056af4ac6e5aa62967aef2619d9d48ad.jpeg)

[image]

[Ref 2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/product-selector-card/2pb_6015f.pdf)
[image]

[Ref 3](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max9939.pdf)

[image]

Comment: my bad  fixed TY. Does this method of defining specs make sense to you?  Because the implementations in other answers may not be right but might be considered. I would expect 3kV 100pF ESD rating and protection added as well. or worse yet connecting a cable of 10 m 1nF charged up to 1kV after dragging in on a dusty plastic tile floor.

Comment: I think it;s a useful answer (+1), although perhaps a bit tangential to the OP's question, and with more detail than really needed. Something that might be added would be a means for clamping the signals to the amplifiers to the supply rails, or perhaps with a shunt TVS.

Comment: Roger that @PStechPaul but for PGA's rated for 200V means high front end attenuation or higher $ priced PGA.  This one was only rated for 60V and my schematic shows 5:1 front end scaling to 40V while others do not.  So the devil is in these details I show that some may not understand.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks a lot Tony. Actually I was looking for these details. As I've left a comment above, my main question is: How can a scope endure 400Vpk input voltage even with 1V/div settings + 1x probe + analog components that takes AVDD of 5V. Could you also share your opinion about this ?

Comment: Using a 5:1 divider is now 40V then with a gain of 0.05 = 2V into ADC  then 10 divisions is 20V so you need a 20V to 40V offset to get in range on-screen scaled by 5 = 4V  or 8V to centre it, which are all in range with this design spec I created.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Hi Tony, thanks for the answer but that was not my question. I don't care how much distortion there will be on signal. Rather, I wonder whether the ICs on the signal path can survive with high voltage input with 1x probe + 1V/div vertical scale setting. Note that Siglent's or Tektronix's 100 MHz scope do not have 200 V opamps on their signal chain.

Comment: I did not attempt to define any design but answered in a way with design specs to show how you can attenuate front end to Vin stress limit while boosting front end gain to achieve a net gain in my spec. So I disagree with your observation that i did not answer your question. Too bad you do not agree. 
I  addressed the linear range and not clamp circuits.